# TcpDump shows ICMP reply but PING times out

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing

I'm trying to redirect network traffic for a specific user account (vpnnet) to an OpenVPN server. The tunnel is working fine when the default route is pulled, but I do not want to route all traffic through VPN, only for processes running with a given UID. So I disabled the automatic pulling of the default route and came up with the following:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner vpnnet -j MARK --set-mark 42
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 table 42
ip rule add fwmark 42 table 42
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -m mark --mark 42 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.1.100
```

The local address is `10.1.1.100` and `10.1.1.1` is the remote gateway.

```
ifconfig
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.1.1.100
        inet6 ****::****::****::****::****  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 128  bytes 10032 (9.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 108  bytes 8832 (8.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
ip route show
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
10.1.1.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.100 metric 50
172.31.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.1.100 metric 100
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 100
```

```
ip route show table 42
default via 10.1.1.1 dev tun0
```

When starting a shell under the user `vpnuser` and pinging the Google DNS server `8.8.8.8` the ping has 100% packet loss. TcpDump shows that requests are going out and replies are coming in on the correct interface:

```
tcpdump -nn -vv -i tun0
tcpdump: listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
20:33:28.938772 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7713, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.1.1.100 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 5078, seq 1, length 64
20:33:29.029533 ip: (tos 0x48, ttl 115, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 10.1.1.100: ICMP echo reply, id 5078, seq 1, length 64
20:33:29.938962 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7790, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.1.1.100 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 5078, seq 2, length 64
20:33:30.029685 ip: (tos 0x48, ttl 115, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 10.1.1.100: ICMP echo reply, id 5078, seq 2, length 64
20:33:30.938838 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8152, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.1.1.100 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 5078, seq 3, length 64
20:33:31.029179 ip: (tos 0x48, ttl 115, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 10.1.1.100: ICMP echo reply, id 5078, seq 3, length 64
```

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 11001ms
```

The iptables log does not show any dropped packets.

The operating system is CentOS 7.

I would be very thankful if somebody could point me into the right direction.

Comment: Post the solution in an answer below, not in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question and to help others having this problem... Reverse Path Filtering kicked in and `rp_filter` dropped the packets, see [explanation](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/rp_filter-and-lpic-3-linux-security/). The solution was setting the rp_filter value to `2` for the `tun0` interface.

Comment: i have similar issue, but no pkt filtering etc. https://superuser.com/questions/1824072/linux-rhel-8-icmp-ping-fails-to-some-interfaces

Comment: @rajeev: please post the ouput of sysctl -ar '\.rp_filter'